# how to not lose branches when cloning a cloned git repo

Tags: git, git-svn

we have a git svn repo that fetches from svn and shows all the branches.
we then have a bare clone of that which people can push to which only shows branches that have tracking branches on the git-svn repo. it's a pain having to make a tracking branch for everything.

is there some way to keep all the branches when cloning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did You used git --mirror option, it implies --bare so just replace it

Comment: --mirror did exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify in your clone command that you want it to mirror all branches.